# How to bind data to DropDownList in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I want to bind Data from DB to DropDownList ,i had tried the following method but the data is not binded to the dropdown can any one tell where am i doing wrong

this is my controller

```
         [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
         public ActionResult AddNew()
          {
        ViewBag.RoleName = new SelectList(GetRoles(), "RoleID", "RoleName");
        return View();
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> GetRoles()
       {
        var roles = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("Select GroupId,EmplopyeeRole from  EmployeeGroup", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);         
            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                var model = new ResourceModel();
                model.RoleId = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["GroupId"]);
                model.RoleName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmplopyeeRole"].ToString();
            }          
        conn.Close();
        return roles;
    }
```

this is my model

```
              public class ResourceModel
{
    public static List<ResourceModel> GetList { get; set; }
    public Int16 EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeEmailId { get; set;}
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeePassword { get; set; }

    public static List<SelectListItem> GetRoles { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }      

}
```

this is my aspxPage

```
    <%:Html.DropDownList("RoleName")%>
```

when i put a breakpoint and see that i have the data in GetRoles Method..can any one tell me where am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is you have a property in the model with the name `RoleName` and also you have it in the `ViewBag`.

So when you use `<%:Html.DropDownList("RoleName")%>` there is a kind of confusion.

I would suggest change `ViewBag.RoleName` into something like `ViewBag.Roles` and then try,

`<%:Html.DropDownList("Roles")%>`

Answer (score 0):

in for loop, use `roles.add(new SelectList{.Value=i, .Text=i});` fields instead of `i`

in view page use `<%: Html.DropDownList("RoleName", New SelectList(youClass.GetRoles, "Value", "Text"))%>` and youClass import page.

linq and foreach is also easy to use~ and Develop as a suitable extension method.

Comment: sorry i dnt get you...can you tell me where i have to add that statement